# Is there any instance VM Scale Set private IP address change (Kubernetes Node)?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have configured Kubernetes with 4 node and the IP addresses are assigned with some ranges

- node1: 172.25.10.4 - 172.25.10.34
- node2: 172.25.10.35 - 172.25.10.65
- node3: 172.25.10.66 - 172.25.10.96
- node4:172.25.10.97 - 172.25.10.127

But in the VM Scale Set Instance each nodes are assigned with the static IP.

Will the private IP change at any instance?
Why this range of IPs are assigned for a single node?

Answer (score 1):

No, they won't change at any point in time (well, when you upgrade your cluster you nodes will get recreated, so these IP addresses will get shuffled a bit). They are assigned because pods are getting assigned those IP addresses from the Virtual Network. By default 30 pods can run on a single host, so 30 + 1 (host IP address) IP addresses are assigned to each host.

But you shouldn't really depend on those IP addresses at all.